# do inner functions have a substantial impact when used in series.apply() in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

In pandas, if I use series.apply() to apply a function with an inner function definition, for example:

```
def square_times_two(x):
  def square(y):
    return y ** 2
  return square(x) * 2

data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df["col_3"] = df.col_1.apply(square_times_two)
```

is the inner function redefined for each row? would there be a performance impact to having many inner functions in a function applied to a large series?

Comment: Did you consider using the disassembler to see the generated code, to see if it recreates the function each time?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't redefine the function each time it's called. You can see this if you disassemble the function:

```
>>> dis.dis(square_times_two)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object square at 0x7fadc028ec90, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('square_times_two.<locals>.square')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (square)

  4           8 LOAD_FAST                1 (square)
             10 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             16 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             18 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object square at 0x7fadc028ec90, file "<stdin>", line 2>:
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (y)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 BINARY_POWER
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

When you define `square_times_two()` it compiles both the main function and the inner function. It does have to use the `MAKE_FUNCTION` operator to turn it into a function object with the appropriate environment, but that should have little overhead since the inner function doesn't close over any variables in the main function.

Comment: as you state, it does not _recompile_ the function. But actually, "MAKE_FUNCTION" is what I'd call "redefining the function" - and Python still have a lot of work doing that. If functions can be moved to external definitions (that is: they make no use of nonlocal variables in the enclosing scope), they definitely should!

Comment: Since it's not a closure, it shouldn't really need to do much.

Comment: so it sounds like it has an impact, but a relatively small one since it isn't recompiling. but for best optimization i should move the inner functions to the same scope as square_times_two?

Comment: If you need to microoptimize, yes.